# Show Div if URL is exactly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to figure out the javascript (I can use jquery as well) that would show a div ID (#main, I have it set in the css to display: none;) if the URL was exactly something like:

```
http://test.testdomain.com/news
```

but not on anything like this

```
http://test.testdomain.com/news/34
http://test.testdomain.com/news/96
http://test.testdomain.com/news/341254
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the condition you need:

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase() == 'http://test.testdomain.com/news') {
    $('#main').show();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution - What URL did you navigate to? What do you see in the browser's dev console when you do `console.log(window.location.href);` ?

Comment: I get http://test.testdomain.com/news (http:// is included but showing it as a link)

Comment: koby...the others will pass indexOf conditional also

Comment: @charlietfl I think that is what the OP means... Let me see his next comment.

Comment: @user1683991  I am restoring my previous answer since it's 100% correct.

Comment: my point is ... *"but not on anything like this"* ... @user1683991 make sure element exists when you run that

Comment: I dont think you should rely on text existing in a string for this type of thing. It can pretty easily match false positives and matching more precisely isnt any more difficult.

Comment: another shorter way would be `location.pathname === '/news'`

Comment: @charlietfl Thought of that, but isn't that problematic in some browsers?

Comment: no reason it should be the `location` standard is pretty solid